# Aside the White House press conference, can the U.S. government give other types of access to certain journalists and news organizations?

Tags: united-states, government, media

In November 2018, Jim Acosta had his press credentials revoked by the White House, thereby barring his access to the White House press conferences.

CNN brought a lawsuit naming the president himself, among others, for both 1st amendment and 5th amendment violations. To my surprise, a judge agreed and ordered the White House to immediately reinstate Jim Acosta's press credentials.

https://www.cnn.com/cnn/2018/11/16/media/cnn-trump-lawsuit-hearing/index.html

Aside the White House press conference, can the U.S. government give other types of access to certain journalists and news organizations? I was thinking since they revoked his access without thinking it through, I think there might be other access the White House can give or not give to journalists and news organizations, but I couldn't find anything on this particular question.

Comment: Depending on the scope of what you’re asking, there are other departments that also do press conferences, notably the pentagon, but also state + city governments sometimes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Leaks* are a well-known type of access - sometimes intentionally used to test the public reaction before going official with a decision/policy; but there may be rogue leaks by functionaries seeking some gain, publicity, good personal relations with press or simply career officials in opposition to the party holding the White House.

One may also get  *interviews* with the members of the administration. But this is unlikely, if the one is even denied the access to press-conferences.